# What happens when rollback is done with auto commit = false?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm not sure if I understand the concepts correctly,

If I have:

```
try{
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  Statement st= conn.createStatement();

  // valid statement
  String statement1 = ....;
  st.executeUpdate(statement1)

  // invalid statement that will cause an error
  String statement2 = ....;
  st.executeUpdate(statement2)

}catch(SQLException e){
  // there was an error
  conn.rollback();
```

Are both statements discarded? or does it only ignore statement2 and statement1 goes through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [Connection#rollback()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback()):

> Undoes all changes made in the current transaction and releases any database locks currently held by this Connection object. This method should be used only when auto-commit mode has been disabled.

This means that *everything* which happened inside your wrapped transaction would be rolled back.  Should the error occur on the second update, implying that the first update succeeded, then perhaps only the first update would need to be reversed.

The transaction you showed us allows your two updates to happen *atomically*, or at least appear this way, to all threads which might be running in the database.  Part of this requirement is that the entire transaction succeeds or fails.  If the latter case, rollback is what is used in the case of failure to take the database back to the starting point before the transaction was attempted.

Answer (score 0):

A working example that you require in the scenario that you mention is available at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-transactions.htm) place.

Here is the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) that talks about this behavior.

Setting the `autocommit()` to false suggests that you as a programmer wants to take control of committing the transaction, based on the outcome of your DML queries.

To answer your question, in the case that you've mentioned none of the INSERT statements would succeed.

Hope you got the information that you seek!